# NVIDIA accelerated ffmpeg (nvenc_h264 ) is dead slow on Amazon G2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, nvidia

FFMPEG when compiled with following options give abysmal performance on Amazon G2 instance( g2.2xlarge, GRID K520) when compared with standalone Dell-Precision-T1700 (Quadro-k620)

```
"--enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable pthreads [b]--enable-nvenc[/b] --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-doc --enable-libmp3lame"
```

Above ffmpeg binary took 66 seconds to transcode 5.22 mins BVE_Localize.mp4 file with following command.

time ffmpeg -y -i BVE_Localize.mp4 -strict -2 -vcodec nvenc_h264 -b 5000k -acodec aac  -ab 256k -f mpegts BVELocalize.ts ( took 1m6.990s on G2)

When same ffmpeg command is executed on Dell-Precision-T1700 (Xeon Dual core, Quadro K620) based workstation takes 0m41.572s.

I would like ffmpeg to perform better on Amazon G2 instance. What do you think I might be missing? My Amazon G2 instance configuration is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, Cuda 7.0 , 352.55 drivers, MSI disabled,NVIDIA SDK 5.0.1